# Java 8 on Windows 10: untrusted website certificate error

Tags: java, windows, security, certificate

I am using Windows 10 version 1703,
Java version 8.131,
and I have experienced this certificate issue with Java app.I am always getting this error that website is not trusted and that certificate is not valid. 
So I added that site that app is trying to access to Exception Site list. And I have also imported certificate from this website to the Java keystore. Still, I am experiencing same issue over and over again.
Certificate is issued by GoDaddy, and is still valid (not expired)
I've also tried to install jre 7u79 to lower security level but it cannot be installed on this version of Windows 10.

[Print-screen error/certificate/security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HukrC.jpg)

Total hours spent on this issue so far ~5hours.
If someone has some tips, would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I forgot to mention. Same app, same procedure, same Java version, different OS (Linux Mint), and there it works!

Comment: You need to add the CA/Sub CA certificates to the 'Trusted Root Certificate Authorities' or 'Intermediate Certificate Authorities' in the browser.

Comment: I basically start .jnlp java app with double click and thats where I get error.

Comment: @spaceman117X, I am facing the same issue. What was the fix you made to resolve it?

Comment: @SaikiranGosikonda No, not really. We used https instead. Also, the IT support from that company that developed that software did not had the solution (at the time)